# Copy/move elision versus explicitly deleted copy/move constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics, delete-operator, copy-elision

I want to know when copy/move elision applies (or is allowed to apply) to explicitly `delete`d copy/move constructors and to non-`delete`d copy/move constructors. Here are the specifics:

1. Can an explicitly `delete`d copy ctor or move ctor get elided? Is an attempt to construct an object from another same-type object or temporary object ever allowed to succeed by skipping over the `delete`d copy ctor and/or `delete`d move ctor?

   Here’s what happens in VC12 (with which I’m not sure if there is an option to disable copy/move elision):

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   struct Foo {
       Foo() { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; }
       Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
       Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
   };

   int main() {
                            // ----Output------
       Foo{ Foo() };        // "default ctor"
       Foo f;               // "default ctor"
       Foo{ std::move(f) }; // error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(Foo &&)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
       Foo{ f };            // error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
   }
   ```

   Even though IntelliSense complains about `Foo{ Foo() };`: `Error: function “Foo::Foo(Foo &&)” ... cannot be referenced – it is a deleted function`, the compiler doesn't complain there, so that line still compiles.
2. Why does `Foo{ Foo() };` work, but not `Foo{ std::move(f) };`? If one call elides the move ctor, then shouldn’t the other?
3. Why does `Foo{ Foo() };` work, but not `Foo{ f };`? This selectivity looks arbitrary. This kind of arbitrary preference of rvalue reference over const reference (or vice versa) doesn’t seem to apply to non-ctor methods; where in a call, if a `delete`d overload that would otherwise have a higher overload resolution priority than a non-`delete`d overload, the `delete`d one blocks the non-`delete`d one, resulting in a compiler error:

   ```
   struct Bar {
       void g(int const&) {}
       void g(int&&) = delete;
   };

   //…
   Bar b;
   b.g(2); //error C2280: 'void Bar::g(int &&)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
   // ^ Would have compiled had function `g(int&&)` been commented out.
   ```

   According to that logic, a `delete`d `Foo(Foo&&)` shouldn’t block a call to `Foo(Foo const&)` when the argument is not a temporary; `Foo(Foo&&)` would have a lower overload resolution priority than `Foo(Foo const&)` in that case.
4. I tried the same `Foo` example in g++ 4.8 with copy elision disabled (via the flag `-fno-elide-constructors`) and again with it enabled. Both g++ trials gave:

   `error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(Foo&&)'` for `Foo{ Foo() };` and

   `error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'` for `Foo{ f };`

   Which compiler is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ms VC ++ has a very old well-known bug. From the C++ Standard

> [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed
>   regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the
>   constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected
>   constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. —end note ]

Comment: The criteria when implementations are allowed to omit copy/move construction of a class object is described in paragraph #31 of section 12.8 Copying and moving class objects of the C++ Standard.It is a long enough paragraph.