# Possible bug in handling the `default` keyword in VS2015 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer

While testing the VS2015 C++ compiler I stumbled upon a strange bug with the `default` keyword.  If I do:

```
struct Dummy
{
    Dummy() = default;
    Dummy(const Dummy &) = delete;
};  

int main()
{
    const Dummy& ref = Dummy();
    return 0;
}
```

I get

> error C2280: 'Dummy::Dummy(const Dummy &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
>   note: see declaration of 'Dummy::Dummy'

But if I use an empty constructor

```
struct Dummy
{
    Dummy() {}
    Dummy(const Dummy &) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    const Dummy& ref = Dummy();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles.  Running the first example with [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1178b084a9fdad3f) or [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0edc19b44ee1ea35) produces no error.

Why would using the default constructor with VS2015 try to use the copy constructor where it doesn't in g++ or clang?

Comment: What do you get from `const Dummy& r2{Dummy()};` ?

Comment: Related: [Copy/move elision versus explicitly deleted copy/move constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589622)

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264984/c-compiler-error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-in-visual

Comment: @BenVoigt it is the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is definitely a bug in VS 2015.

In C++11, assigning temporary to const reference must not call copy constructor, but VS 2015 does.

You can check it with

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dummy
{
    Dummy() = default;
    Dummy(const Dummy &) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    void test() const { std::cout << "test" << std::endl; }
};  

int main()
{
    const Dummy& ref = Dummy();
    ref.test();
    return 0;
}
```

compiled on VS 2013, 2015, gcc and clang. Only VS (any version) calls copy constructor, if class constructor defined as `= default`.

I think VS compiiler still in 2015 erroneously uses old C++03 standard rules for this (8.5.3.5 of C++03):

> If the initializer expression is an rvalue, with T2 a class type, and
>   "cv1 T1" is reference-compatible with "cv2 T2," the reference is bound
>   in one of the following ways (the choice is implementation-defined):
>
> -- The reference is bound to the object represented by the rvalue (see 3.10) or to a sub-object within that object.
>
> -- A temporary of type "cv1 T2" [sic] is created, and a constructor is called to copy the entire rvalue object into the temporary. The
>   reference is bound to the temporary or to a sub-object within the
>   temporary.
>
> The constructor that would be used to make the copy shall be callable
>   whether or not the copy is actually done.

VS developers chose second way. They corrected this for empty user-defined constructor (`{}`), but forgot to do this for defaulted (`= default`) constructors.

PS. [Bug on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1849804) (please vote)

Comment: Still experiencing this bug with VS Pro 2017