# Initialize an array member of class when class's copy constructor is deleted

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2015

Here is a smaller version of a use case that I am working on.

```
#include <mutex>
template<typename T = float>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x, int y):m_mutex(){}
private:
    std::mutex  m_mutex; // This is must have in my project
};

typedef Foo<float> Foo_typedef;

class Func
{
public:     
    static Foo_typedef static_array[2];
};

Foo_typedef Func::static_array[2] = { Foo_typedef(2,3), Foo_typedef(2,3) };

int main()
{   
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling this VS 2015 Update 2 emits following errors.

```
error C2280: 'Foo<float>::Foo(const Foo<float> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
note: see declaration of 'Foo<float>::Foo'
```

I looked around and I suspected that there might one of the two reasons this.

1) Copy constructor member for `std::mutex` is deleted

2) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784399/possible-bug-in-handling-the-default-keyword-in-vs2015-c) which I thought might be similar to what I am seeing.

Which one is it? What can I do to bypass this error thrown by VS 2015 Update 2 compiler?

**UPDATE**:Updated the constructor which takes in some parameters that are needed to be passed to `Foo_typedef`.

Comment: Could you simply drop the initializers? i.e. `Foo_typedef Func::static_array[2];`

Comment: `Foo_typedef Func::static_array[2]{};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct the element in place using the constructor:

```
Foo_typedef Func::static_array[2] = { {2, 3}, {2, 3} };
```

With this, there are no copy or move because the two elements are constructed *in place*.

The standard says (§8.5.1/2 [dcl.init.aggr], emphasis is mine):

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, [...] the elements of the initializer list are taken as **initializers for the members of the aggregate** [...].

In your case, it means that `Foo_typedef(2,3)` will be taken as an *initializer* for your `Foo_typedef` and thus a copy will be needed. In the code I gave, `{2, 3}` will be taken as an *initializer* and the corresponding constructor will be called (no copy).